# How do i replace a visually selected range with the contents of the paste buffer in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to replace a selection of text with is present in the default paste buffer. Say, I yanked a word with yaw and now I want to replace a word with that, how do I do it?

I saw similar questions answered with suggestions to use a named register and delete the text-to-be-replaced into the black hole etc, but I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: By visually selected, you mean you've used 'v' and highlighted the text?

Comment: Yes jetru, that's what I meant.

Comment: That question you reference also talks about the answer accepted here.  FWIW.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visually select the range, then type `p`.

Comment: If you want to keep the contents of your default register, in order to paste it another time, do like me: `xnoremap p pgvy`. @Paul Tomblin: Could you edit your answer maybe to include it?

Comment: @Benoit, what does that do?  Obviously it maps 'p' to 'p' followed by 'gv' by 'y', what what does 'gv' do?

Comment: why don't you ask vim help? `:h gv` >> Start Visual mode with the same area as the previous area and the same mode. In Visual mode the current and the previous Visual area are exchanged. After using "p" or "P" in Visual mode the text that was put will be selected.